# How can I insert values at map to list pair?

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, stl

My container is like this:

```
map<DWORD, list<pair<string,LARGE_INTEGER>>> map_to_list_items;
```

This code fails to compile:

```
map<DWORD, list<pair<string,LARGE_INTEGER>>>::iterator iter_map_to_list_items = map_list_items.find(dwThreadID);
if ( iter_map_to_list_items == map_to_list_items.end() )
{
    map_to_list_itens.insert ( pair<DWORD,pair<string,LARGE_INTEGER>>(dwTheadID, (string("Start"), m_TimePRE)));
}
```

Comment: What error is your compiler saying?

Comment: The map's value type is a list of pairs, but you're trying to insert just a pair

Comment: I see you are closing your templates with `>>>` rather than `> > >` (note spaces). Are you using C++11?

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question embedding the answer...

Comment: It's ugly "correct solution"! One or two lines (at most), should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you have two variables like this:

```
map<DWORD, list<pair<string, LARGE_INTEGER>>> map_to_list_items;
map<DWORD, list<pair<string, LARGE_INTEGER>>> map_list_tempos_threads;
```

The first thing you can do to simplify your code is to use the new C++11's `auto` keyword, instead of explicitly typing the whole cumbersome iterator name:

```
auto it = map_list_tempos_threads.find(dwThreadID);
```

(Note that you may have some typos in your code, since you had `dwTheadID` instead of `dwThreadID`, and `..._itens` instead of `..._items`).

Then, you can simply use `std::map::operator[]` overload to insert the new item in the map, if it was not there:

```
if (it == map_to_list_items.end())
{
    //
    // Insert the new list<pair<string, LARGE_INTEGER>> in the map,
    // assuming:
    //   -  key: dwThreadID
    //   -  string: "Start"
    //   -  LARGE_INTEGER: m_TimePRE
    //

    list<pair<string, LARGE_INTEGER>> l;    
    string s = "Start";
    l.push_back(make_pair(s, m_TimePRE))     // I'm assuming m_TimePRE is a LARGE_INTEGER
    map_to_list_items[dwThreadID] = move(l); // Move the list into the map
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is a much shorter version for the insertion code:

```
map_to_list_items[dwThreadID].emplace_back("Start", m_TimePRE);
```

The key point is that, if `dwThreadID` (the *"key"*) is *not* in the map, a default-constructed *"value"* (i.e. `list<pair<string, LARGE_INTEGER>>`) is created in the map by the `operator[]` overload, and a reference to it is returned.
Then, `list::emplace_back()` is called on that reference, and the new `("Start", m_TimePRE)` pair is added to the (previously empty, since default-constructed) list.

With this form there is much less to type, but several operations happen "under the hood"; instead, in the first form, the code and its logical steps are more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert `pair<string, LARGE_INTEGER>` as `list<pair<string, LARGE_INTEGER>>`.

I.e. you have a `map<D, list<pair<S, L>>` which looks like this:

`D1 -> list [pair1, pair2, pair3, ...]`

`D2 -> list [pair4, ...]`

**What you are trying to do:**

`D3 -> pairX`,

**What you should do:**

`D3 -> list[pairX]`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> map<DWORD, list<pair<string,LARGE_INTEGER>>> map_to_list_itens;
> ```

So you have map, with value of type

> ```
> list<pair<string,LARGE_INTEGER>>
> ```

after you are trying to add to map (as value / *"second argument"*) just a pair (another thing, wrong type).

> ```
> ( pair<DWORD,pair<string,LARGE_INTEGER>>(dwTheadID, (string("Start"), m_TimePRE)));
> ```

If you have

```
 map<T1, list<pair<T2,T3> > > my_map;
```

you should adding to list otherwise. Like here:

```
 my_map[T1_object].push_back(make_pair(T2_object, T3_object)); //or
 my_map[T1_object].push_back(T2_T3_pair_object);
 //or in C++11
 my_map[T1_object].emplace_back(T2,T3);
```

More about it, you can read in reference, [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map), [list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). I suggest to start with [easier example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/) to understand how it works, like here.

Comment: This is the cleanest and most readable way to do it. `my_map[non_existent_key]` automatically inserts a default constructed (empty) `list<pair<T2,T3> >` and returns a reference to it if `non_existent_key` is not in the map.